# Why does jmp -1 assemble to ebfd?

Tags: assembly, x86

I know that fb encodes -3 and that during jmp execution, rip is the adress of the next instruction
But I am confused, I thought the operand of jmp modifies the value of rip by that value (-1).
Am I misunderstanding something, or is -1 supposed to be interpreted as the adress of the byte **just before jmp instruction ?**

Comment: If your short jump instruction is stored at offset zero then the address after its two bytes of machine code is offset 2. Add the displacement of -3 and you end up at the destination offset of -1.

Comment: Which assembler are you programming for?  I think the semantics of jumps with immediates for operands depend on the assembler.

Comment: This is about your assembler rather than the architecture.  Apparently when you give a numeric operand to `jmp`, it interprets it as an offset from the *current* instruction, and adjusts the displacement accordingly.  Maybe you'd think it would just encode the number directly into the instruction, but apparently that is not what it does.  Check its documentation.